# Where does Django check framework functions live?

Tags: django

The django framework allows you to write your own checks https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/checks/ but it says nothing about where that code should live and how it is hooked into the check framework.  Any ideas on how this is done?

Answer (score 3):

#### #1 Where should it live?

It completely up to you! I usually place offhand stuff like this in
`{root}/common`, specifically `{root}/common/internal`. I'm not sure if this
is a good practice but it works for me!

#### #2 How is it hooked into check framework

Not 100% sure what you mean, but all you have to do is import the file inside an
`{root}/{app}/apps.py` file and your check will be ran when you run any server commands; like `python manage.py runserver`

---

Here's an example check I tested that checks that my `TESTING` var in `settings.py` is a valid Boolean.

##### common/internal/checks.py

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.checks import Error, Tags, Warning, register

E001 = Error(
    "'%s' is an Invalid Setting for TESTING. Must be a Bool" % settings.TESTING,
    id='settings_testing.E001',
)

@register(Tags.compatibility)
def check_testing(app_configs, **kwargs):
    if not isinstance(settings.TESTING, bool):
        return [E001]
    return []
```

##### app1/apps.py

```py
from django.apps import AppConfig

from common.internal.checks import check_testing

class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'app1'
```

##### Example Failure Output

- `djrun` -> `python manage.py runserver`, good alias! would recommend

```bash
λ djrun
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "[REDACTED]", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "[REDACTED]", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "[REDACTED]", line 469, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (caches.E001) 'blah' is an Invalid Setting for TESTING. Must be a Bool

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).
```